# A strange horizontal line on monitor

Tags: display

Running Fedora 21 Workstation.

On my monitor, there is a strange horizontal line around 1/3rd the distance from the top.

The line remains whether I am looking at a web page or working on a document.

Even the boot screen shows the line.

What could be wrong? How do I set it right?

Comment: What model of monitor is it? Is the line a particular color?

Comment: Try squeezing the plastic bezel on the sides in the general vicinity of the line.  Does that change anything?  Is the line dark or bright?

Comment: If it shows up in the boot (bios) screens as well *and* it is using an analog connection (VGA, dvi-a) then the fault is in the monitor. If you use a digital connection (dvi-d, HDMI) then the problem is in your video card.

Comment: Its seems like a faulty monitor. Can you post a picture of what you are seeing?

Comment: If it's a CRT there should also be one at ⅓ from the bottom - the 'Trinitron line'